# Does every null-homologous surface bound, part deux

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159411/0-homologous-surface-bounds), and Mark Grant's excellent answer. The answer shows that the answer is yes, but what if one were under a strange compunction to actually construct the submanifold that the surface bounds (assuming that the ambient space is given by a triangulation)? Does the spectral sequence machine imply an algorithm, and if not, is there some other way?

Comment: The spectral sequence should give you an algorithm in principle.  In low dimensions like that, the obstructions are usually readily dealt with quite explicitly.  A not very effective procedure to find the 3-manifold would be to take the exterior of the surface, triangulate it and look for the 3-manifold as a "normal" 3-manifold in that triangulation. One might have to subdivide the triangulation for the 3-manifold to appear as a vertex-normal solution.

Comment: Good question! There should be some way to take the null-homology and resolve the singularities, and perhaps this can be made algorithmic, but I don't see how this should be related to the spectral sequence. One question: is it clear that the surface bounds a *submanifold*? I don't see why the 3-manifold needs to be embedded.

Comment: @MarkGrant No, now that you mention it, it is not clear, though I have a bit set that this is true, for some reason...

Comment: The classical method of Kneser for eliminating singularities should work in this setting. (cite: a la recherche de la topologie perdue, page 61. http://www.zbmath.org/?q=an:03962761)